# Fastest union for multiple sorted lists removing duplicates and get an ordered result

Tags: python, python-3.x

When having a list of lists in which all the sublists are ordered e.g.:
`[[1,3,7,20,31], [1,2,5,6,7], [2,4,25,26]]` 
what is the fastest way to get the union of these lists without having duplicates in it and also get an ordered result?
So the resulting list should be:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,20,25,26,31]` .
I know I could just union them all without duplicates and then sort them but are there faster ways (like: do the sorting while doing the union) built into python?

EDIT:

Is the proposed answer faster than executing the following algorithm pairwise with all the sublists?

[SOLUTION. UNION(x, y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JjQ9.png)
1 answer<-()
2 while x != NIL and y != NIL
3 do if docID(x) = docID(y)
4 then ADD(answer, docID(x))
5 x<-next(x)
6 y<-next(y)
7 else if docID(x)<docID(y)
8 then ADD(answer, docID(x))
9 x<-next(x)
10 else ADD(answer, docID(y))
11 y<-next(y)
12 return(answer)

Comment: Please replace the image with a transcription of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) for this:

```
from heapq import merge

def mymerge(v):
    last = None
    for a in merge(*v):
        if a != last:  # remove duplicates
            last = a
            yield a

print(list(mymerge([[1,3,7,20,31], [1,2,5,6,7], [2,4,25,26]])))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 25, 26, 31]
```

Comment: In what way is it not Pythonic?

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin how is this not Pythonic? It's a pretty good use of the standard library, and an elegant use of a generator. I'd say it's *very* Pythonic.

Comment: Note that this solution comes with a small caveat of requiring the first item of the merged sequence to be not `None`.

Comment: because the function looks pretty ugly and not obviously for such simple case.

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin "looks ugly"? It looks fine. Simple, self-documenting, and Pythonic. And it happens to be correct...

Comment: @blhsing a good solution is to use `last = object()` instead of `last = None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed that's much more elegant than using a separate flag to signify the first iteration.

Comment: Could you also provide some timings addressing the "fastest" part of the question? :-)

Comment: @norok2 algorithmically this is the fastest, but for reasonable sized inputs, I suspect simply `sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)))` is quite competitive

Comment: You can use `itertools.groupby` to eliminate duplicates - `[x for x, _ in itertools.groupby(merge(*v))]` is a one-liner.

Comment: By the way, the time complexity of this solution is O(*n* log *k*) where *n* is the sum of the list lengths, and *k* is the number of lists.

Comment: Regarding sequences starting with `None`, `None` is not orderable, so it cannot be included in a legal input to `merge` anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, `sorted(set(...))` seems to be much faster than the `heapq.merge()` approach. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380118/5218354) for some timings and some other (slower) solutions. I actually find this a bit counter-intuitive since, if we forget the unicity constrain, `heapq.merge()` should have all the ingredients to go faster than `sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable())`, yet it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

(EDITED)

The asymptotic theoretical best approach to the problem is to use the priority queue, like, for example, the one implemented in `heapq.merge()` (thanks to @kaya3 for pointing this out).

However, in practice, a number of things can go wrong. For example the constant factors in the complexity analysis are large enough that a theoretically-optimal approach is, in real-life scenarios, slower.
This is fundamentally dependent on the implementation.
For example, Python suffer some speed penalty for explicit looping.

So, let's consider a couple of approaches and how the do perform for some concrete inputs.

## Approaches

Just to give you some idea of the numbers we are discussing, here are a few approaches:

- `merge_sorted()` which uses the most naive approach of flatten the sequence, reduce it to a `set()` (removing duplicates) and sort it as required

```
import itertools


def merge_sorted(seqs):
    return sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(seqs)))
```

---

- `merge_heapq()` which essentially [@arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361748/5218354). Note that the `itertools.groupby()` variation is slightly (less than ~1%) faster.

```
import heapq


def i_merge_heapq(seqs):
    last_item = None
    for item in heapq.merge(*seqs):
        if item != last_item:
            yield item
            last_item = item

def merge_heapq(seqs):
    return list(i_merge_heapq(seqs))
```

---

- `merge_bisect_set()` is substantially the same algorithm as `merge_sorted()` except that the result is now constructed explicitly using the *efficient* `bisect` module for sorted insertions. Since `sorted()` is doing fundamentally the same thing but looping in Python, this is not going to be faster.

```
import itertools
import bisect


def merge_bisect_set(seqs):
    result = []
    for item in set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(seqs)):
        bisect.insort(result, item)
    return result
```

---

- `merge_bisect_cond()` is similar to `merge_bisect_set()` but now the non-repeating constraint is explicitly done using the final `list`. However, this is much more expensive than just using `set()` (in fact it is so slow that it was excluded from the plots).

```
def merge_bisect_cond(seqs):
    result = []
    for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(seqs):
        if item not in result:
            bisect.insort(result, item)
    return result
```

---

- `merge_pairwise()` explicitly implements the the theoretically efficient algorithm, similar to what you outlined in your question.

```
def join_sorted(seq1, seq2):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    len1, len2 = len(seq1), len(seq2)
    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        if seq1[i] < seq2[j]:
            result.append(seq1[i])
            i += 1
        elif seq1[i] > seq2[j]:
            result.append(seq2[j])
            j += 1
        else:  # seq1[i] == seq2[j]
            result.append(seq1[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
    if i < len1:
        result.extend(seq1[i:])
    elif j < len2:
        result.extend(seq2[j:])
    return result


def merge_pairwise(seqs):
    result = []
    for seq in seqs:
        result = join_sorted(result, seq)
    return result
```

---

- `merge_loop()` implements a generalization of the above, where now pass is done only once for all sequences, instead of doing this pairwise.

```
def merge_loop(seqs):
    result = []
    lengths = list(map(len, seqs))
    idxs = [0] * len(seqs)
    while any(idx < length for idx, length in zip(idxs, lengths)):
        item = min(
            seq[idx]
            for idx, seq, length in zip(idxs, seqs, lengths) if idx < length)
        result.append(item)
        for i, (idx, seq, length) in enumerate(zip(idxs, seqs, lengths)):
            if idx < length and seq[idx] == item:
                idxs[i] += 1
    return result
```

---

## Benchmarks

By generating the input using:

```
def gen_input(n, m=100, a=None, b=None):
    if a is None and b is None:
        b = 2 * n * m
        a = -b
    return tuple(tuple(sorted(set(random.randint(int(a), int(b)) for _ in range(n)))) for __ in range(m))
```

one can plot the timings for varying `n`:

[image: bm_full]
[image: bm_zoom]

Note that, in general, the performances will vary for different values of `n` (the size of each sequence) and `m` (the number of sequences), but also of `a` and `b` (the minimum and the maximum number generated).
For brevity, this was not explored in this answer, but feel free to play around with it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mu5WN6xzlI8U9NZ0-GvZEIOmtc6QiWY0), which also includes some other implementations, notably some tentative speed-ups with Cython that were only partially successful.

Comment: *"If you are after the theoretical most efficient algorithm, the pairwise joining traversing the input only once and constructing the output as it goes by, it is probably the most efficient (assuming O(1) append operation)."* No; iteratively merging one more list into the output means you're eventually merging lists of length O(*N*) where *N* is the total number of items, so the time will be O(*Nm*) where *m* is the number of lists. The solution using a priority queue, e.g. `heapq.merge`, takes O(*N* log *m*) time. For comparison, the simple `sorted(set(...))` approach is O(*N* log *N*).

Comment: @kaya3 I believe that `heapq.merge` is actually `O(Nm log Nm)`

Comment: No, *N* is the total number of items and inserting/removing in a priority queue of length *m* takes O(log *m*) time.

Comment: Conceptually, `heapq.merge` is quite similar to the `merge_loop` solution. Both solutions in principle insert the first element of each of the *m* sequences into a priority queue, then keep doing poll-min and inserting the next element from the sequence that poll-min took from. The difference is that `merge_loop`'s "priority queue" is implemented like an unsorted array, so the poll-min operation is O(*m*), whereas the poll-min operation on a heap is O(log *m*). Both algorithms do poll-min O(*N*) times.

Comment: @kaya3 OK, I understood your `N` incorrectly. I was considering the case of `m` lists of length `N`. If `N` is the total number of elements, `heapq.merge` should be `O(2 N log N)` (one pass to construct the heap and one pass to pull it). On the contrary, the pairwise joining goes by `O((N / m) * m²)`, so `O(N m)` and so long as `m < 2 log N`, that is actually more efficient.

Comment: No, `heapq.merge` does not insert all *N* elements into the heap at once; it only needs the `m` current smallest elements from each sequence. You can read the source code: it builds a heap of size *m* and then calls `_heapreplace` for each item, which does both an insert and a remove, leaving the heap as size *m*.  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L314

Comment: @kaya3 OK, still if `m < log(N)` makes pairwise joining theoretically faster.

Comment: No, pairwise joining is O(*Nm*) and `heapq.merge` is O(*N* log *m*). The latter is always asymptotically better.

Comment: OK, I had overlooked that the internal heap of `heapq.merge` is of size `m`. I am convinced now, indeed :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of sets in Python-3.

```
mylist = [[1,3,7,20,31], [1,2,5,6,7], [2,4,25,26]]

mynewlist = mylist[0] + mylist[1] + mylist[2]

print(list(set(mynewlist)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 25, 26, 31]
```

First merge all the sub-lists using list addition.

Then convert it into a set object where it will delete all the duplicates which will also be sorted in ascending order.

Convert it back to list.It gives your desired output.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: This is very inefficient, quadratic time (don't use concatenation to merge a list of lists) **and** it is incorrect, since it isn't sorted

Comment: I think you could do it with unpacking the given lists into the set constructor, but you would still need to convert the unpacked lists into a single iterator. Would then change the 'list' in the final statement to `sorted` which returns a list.